# Rendering Objects one by one?

Tags: rendering

I'd like to render all objects on the blend file and render them one by one seperately.
I'd like it to:

- Render the object on selected collection
- Save it with the obj name as png to folder (if folder name can be the collection name, that'll be pretty life saver)
- Render the next obj

And if i can keep the shadows, that'll be bonus!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'd have to use python for this. Make sure the collection that you'd like to render is selected/active in the *Outliner* and run the following script:

```
import bpy
import os.path

C = bpy.context
scn = C.scene
output_path = scn.render.filepath
exclude_type = ('LIGHT', 'CAMERA', 'ARMATURE', 'LIGHT_PROBE', 'SPEAKER')

# Disable all relevant objects in renders
for ob in C.collection.objects:
    if ob.type not in exclude_type:
        ob.hide_render = True

for ob in C.collection.objects:
    if ob.type not in exclude_type:
        # Enable the object for rendering
        ob.hide_render = False
        # Assemble the path (.jpg is a placeholder)
        scn.render.filepath = os.path.join(output_path, "{}.jpg".format(ob.name))
        # Call the render operator
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
        # Disable the object for rendering
        ob.hide_render = True

# Reset the output path
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_path
# Reset hide_render state
for ob in C.collection.objects:
    if ob.type not in exclude_type:
        ob.hide_render = False
```

Render output of the default scene, added a *Sphere* and a *Cylinder* to the default *Collection*:

```
/tmp/
├── Cube.png
├── Sphere.png
├── Cylinder.png
```

To get the shadow just add a *Plane* to the *Scene Collection*, make it a [*Shadow Catcher*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19765/cycles-shadeless-shadow-catcher-material-for-rendering-onto-footage) (*Object Properties > Visibility*) and enable *Transparent* *(Render Properties > Film)*:

[image]

Render output of the *shadow catcher scene* (Cube.png, Cylinder.png, Sphere.png):

[image]

If you'd like to have a subfolder with the actual name of the collection, just add it to the regular output path e.g. `/tmp/Collection/`.

Related:

- [Cycles: Shadeless "Shadow-catcher" Material for Rendering onto Footage](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19765/cycles-shadeless-shadow-catcher-material-for-rendering-onto-footage)
- [How to make a model cast shadows onto the world texture/background?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How can I batch render lots of objects individually?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208255/how-can-i-batch-render-lots-of-objects-individually)
- [Blender script import model and render it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39303/blender-script-import-model-and-render-it)

Comment: Dude thank you, this literally saved me thousands of minutes!