# Disable object rendering "Camera" option per scene/layer

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, render-layers

I like to create a batch rendering from my scene while having an object as the background which will be present on all the renders and the other objects which I like to have visible per each render. so technically the other two objects will be disabled in the render and only one object will be visible per render.

I tried to create a multiple "linked copy" scene but unfortunately, the render "camera" icon seems to be global and affect all the scenes.

I tried to do the same thing with creating multiple layers but I am still facing the same issue that disabling/enabling render "camera" affects all the scenes/layers

is there a way I could disable render locally and not globally similar to hide/view objects in the viewport?

[image: Example]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241373/rendering-objects-one-by-one/241378#241378

Comment: I think you want to use different view layers and not different scenes, and place your objects accordingly. You can set collection visibility per view layer (the checkbox is in the outliner editor)