# need rendering output of more than 50+ models with single scene setup

Tags: rendering, lighting, scene, output

I have more than 50+ models and I want them render with single environment scene for threejs but we can not change the meterial properties because of clients condition.

How can I set up the scene?

This is render clients want but when we use other models lighting effect changed i know beacuse of different color and meterial properties.

So how to render this many modules without changing there scene light?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/313/is-there-a-way-to-batch-render-multiple-scenes https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241373/rendering-objects-one-by-one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218730/automatically-generate-100-animations-each-with-a-different-texture-input https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208255/how-can-i-batch-render-lots-of-objects-individually